# JSTL based nested iteration

Tags: iterator, nested, jstl

Assume you have the following code:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(myIterator) > 0}">      
    <span>blabla</span>
    <c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myIterator}" varStatus="status">
        // some stuff
    </c:forEach>
    <br />
</c:if>
```

Note that myIterator is an Iterator (surprise, surprise *g).

The problem is that I do not end up in the each loop and do not see "// some stuff" to happen. I think the reason is that fn:length(myIterator) has already iterated over the Iterator to determine its size so that we have already reached the end when arriving at the forEach loop.

I have not seen any elegant way to reset the iterator manually or so.

Of course I could try using scriptlet code (something like <% myIterator.reset() %>, but I would like to avoid that.

I have also tried something like:

```
<c:if test="${not empty myIterator}">
```

But that did not work either (did not even enter the if-clause's body).

Any elegant suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you referring to an Iterator. That should be a Collection like an ArrayList or something.

[an iterator can only be iterated once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848895/using-the-iterator-over-the-same-set-more-than-once-in-java)

[EDIT]

IMHO, the cleanest approach is to change the Java controller to give you a Collection. However, based on your feedback that you dont want to or can't...

1. Change the Java code
2. Use Java scriptlets in your JSP

You can solve this with some Javascript/DHTML. Consider this JSP code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loopHasContent = false;
</script>

<div id="loop-content" style="display:none">
    <span>blabla</span>
    <c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myIterator}" varStatus="status">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        loopHasContent = true;
        </script>
        // some stuff
    </c:forEach>
    <br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(loopHasContent) {
    document.getElementById("loop-content").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

You only reference the `Iterable` once so your issue goes away. The `div` is not displayed by default. As long as your `forEach` loop executes at least once then the javascript variable `loopHasContent` is set to true, otherwise it remains false. The final javascript trailing the div will only show your loop-content if it has to.

Comment: That is out of my "control"; I get that handed over.

Comment: I justed updated with a link. Maybe you can request a new iterable if you can't access the collection directly

Comment: Requesting a new iterable? What do you mean? How can I do that using JSTL only?

Comment: @user1090608 was this answer of any use?