# How do I move a pointer to the front of a linked list after iterating through it?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I'm currently using the Iterator method next() to loop through a linked list. Once I've reached the end, how can I move the pointer to the beginning of the list again so I can loop through it multiple times? Or how can I use a head pointer to do this?
Thanks!

```
public java.util.Iterator<String> iterator() {
    return new java.util.Iterator<String>() {
        private WordNode current = first;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        public String next() {
            String result = current.word;
            current = current.next;
            return result;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `Iterator` can do that for you. You have to record the head in your code.

Comment: Are you making a class iterable? Or are you using a preexisting List?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the iterator over the same set more than once in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848895/using-the-iterator-over-the-same-set-more-than-once-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator, as it said, you have to iterate it one by one.
If you want to iterate from beginning multiple times, you have to store `head` pointer somewhere.

Comment: sorry i'm still learning how to use this website but thank you this was super helpful! :)